# clearTimeout when a function gets called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an alert message bar that slides down when the user clicks a specific link. The alert bar slides back up after a specified period. If the user clicks this link multiple times, I would like to reset the timer, slide the alert bar back up and then slide it down again (reseting the timer).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#main_container').live('click', function(){
        $('.answer_yes').click (function(){


            if ($('#topbar_alert').is(':visible')){

                clearTimeout(slideUpTimer)  

                }

                $('#topbar_alert').slideDown(300);
                $('#topbar_alert_container').empty();
                $('#topbar_alert_container').append('Alert Created!');

                var slideUpTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#topbar_alert').slideUp(300);
                },8000);

        });
    });

});
```

So everything works except the clearTimeout portion. If you click the link, the alert bar slides down and then slides back up after the setTimeout finishes. But if you click the link multiple times, it doesn't reset the alert bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define the `var slideUpTimer` outside the current scope

```
var slideUpTimer;
$('#main_container').live('click', function(){
    $('.answer_yes').click (function(){
        if ($('#topbar_alert').is(':visible')){
            clearTimeout(slideUpTimer)  
        }

        $('#topbar_alert').slideDown(300);
        $('#topbar_alert_container').empty();
        $('#topbar_alert_container').append('Alert Created!');

        slideUpTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('#topbar_alert').slideUp(300);
        },8000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

when you use `var slideUpTimer` inside the function, it only exists for that one execution, it does not persist.

To use `slideUpTimer` as you want to, you'll need to put it in the global scope.

```
var slideUpTimer;
$(document).ready....
```

then assign it with

```
slideUpTimer = setTimeout()...
```

notice the lack of `var` when assigning.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `slideUpTimer` outside your function. Make it global.